# Location of temperature sensors on the mainboard?

Tags: motherboard, thinkpad, temperature, sensors, cpu-temperature

I installed `PSensor` in order to monitor and adjust the CPU fan speed on my ThinkPad R60 (which was overheating) and was surprised to find a total of **14** different temperature readings:

[image: Screenshot]

It seems there is one thermal sensor for each of the two CPU cores ("Core 0/1") and one inside the hard drive ("SAMSUNG"). What are the other ones?

I thought there might be some duplicates, but looking at the time series they appear to be individual sensors. Does anyone have a source or documentation detailing their functions? Or could `PSensor` be failing to read out their designations?

Interestingly, while the other sensors seem to be close to heat sources, "temp5/6" appear to just measure ambient temperature.

The laptop is in use, so tearing it apart, searching and probing for thermistors is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

The sensors are soldered wherever the designers of the pcb decides to put them.  This is for a different motherboard but you can get a good idea of how they are placed:

https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/motherboard-ambient-temperature-sensor-locations-code-markings.229748/

I'm certain with enough time and research you could find out where all the individual sensors are for your system.

Comment: Interesting link, although it doesn't specifically answer the question (it seems some sensors indeed just measure ambient temperature). I know that they are usually mounted on the PCBs (mainboard, hard drive etc.). Some information on which sensor is responsible for which component would be helpful, `PSensor` just names all of them "temp".

Comment: Edited the question to make it clearer